# Business or tourist visa to attend a conference in Taiwan?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, taiwan

I saw [France Business Visa For Attending OpenSource Conference](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95099/france-business-visa-for-attending-opensource-conference) and [Can an Indian passport holder apply for a Taiwan visa without the special documents?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92909/can-an-indian-passport-holder-apply-for-a-taiwan-visa-without-the-special-docume/92910#92910) While both give some details as to how to approach for visa, I am not sure how to get this done.

The last time I did to get a visa was for South Africa and used VFS Global, as they have a branch in Pune and could apply for South Africa from the Pune office.

The benefit of using VFS was that I didn't have to go to Mumbai and saved time and money for both, and my passport was **safe**.

There is [visahq](https://www.visahq.com/) but it seems more expensive than VFS Global for using a similar service. Also, they are in Mumbai, not in [Pune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pune).

My itinerary would probably be around 2 to 3 weeks long, part of which the conference for the first ten days or so, and then ten days doing the typical touristy things, seeing places, eating out and trying to understand the culture, even for just a bit.

If I do go, I will probably be speaking to peers or/and general public without being compensated, and sharing knowledge at the conference.

I am not sure whether to apply for a tourist or business visa for the conference. The 'company' organizing the conference is a non-profit organization based in Taiwan. They are expecting 600+ people from all over the world to come and be part of the conference.

Looking forward to know.

Comment: When speaking to visa and immigration authorities, **avoid** wording like _"couple of speaking gigs"_ if what you really mean is _"give a presentation to my peers - without being paid or otherwise compensated for it - as it is common for ordinary paying attendees at this conference to do"_. They can very easily get into their heads that a "gig" means working for the conference organizers, which would create a lot of trouble for you. If you're really unlucky, attempts to clear up the misunderstanding will be interpreted as "backpedaling once he found out work is not allowed".

Comment: yup, I hear you. I was using common parlance but yeah this could be mis-interpreted. I re-worded it so it doesn't sound commercially-oriented as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Republic of China Visitor Visa](https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-157-248-4f20b-2.html) allows all of your planned activities:

> Foreign nationals, who hold ordinary passports or other legal travel documents and who intend to stay in Taiwan for no more than six months for the purposes  of transit; tour; visit relatives; undertake visits; undertake inspection tours; attend international conferences; conduct business; pursue short-term study; undertake short-term employment; undertake short-term missionary work; and engage in other activities in the ROC as approved by MOFA.